# Invoice, etc. templating system for PDF generation

Tags: pdf, node.js, pdf-generation, invoicing

I'm looking to pull invoice data from an ERP system and create PDF files of the invoices in a similar format to what the ERP system provides.

I can do that, but I'd prefer not to "hard code" the invoice template being used (for where to put the various data fields, etc.) Ideally I'd be interested in a third-party template generator (with a WYSIWYG editor) that is designed for such - and then be able to supply the PDF generation with said template file in order for this system to pull the appropriate data, and generate the PDF with such a template.

The ERP system uses DevExpress XtraReports - while it would be nice to use the same template files, I'm not crazy about that since the invoice template for instance is nearly 4200 lines of code - which seems rather insane if I need to manually support such. (Doing essentially the same template with raw HTML is around 200 lines.)

I'm sure many people have had similar requirements - taking raw document data from a database, and generating a PDF version - be it for reports, purchase orders, invoices, quotes, sales orders, etc. Using something along the lines of Crystal Reports (preferably open-source, although we're not opposed to paying for commercial software) for the template design, and then using that template to generate the PDF documents with the supplied data. (And of course, doing the generation programmatically. I'd prefer to keep that in Node.js to align with the rest of the application.)

With an invoice, it could span multiple pages, and needs to be able to have dynamic header / footer content on each page, with a variable number of lines. This adds a level of complexity.

Ideally would like for users (IT / accounting) to be able to edit templates directly, but may need to resort to having a developer modify an HTML template or such instead.

Here's some I've looked at: (many of these don't support user editable templates)

- https://pdfme.com/ - GUI templating, lacks good support for repeatable lines, multi-page
- https://pspdfkit.com/ - no pricing listed, not sure whether it has a template designer
- https://pdfgeneratorapi.com/ - shows promise, but expensive monthly fee, and not sure how I'd integrate with our firewalled on-premises database
- https://github.com/tawseefnabi/pdf-node - not maintained actively (2yrs ago)
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf - deprecated
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-creator-node - uses deprecated html-pdf
- https://pdfkit.org / https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit - well used and updated
- https://react-pdf.org/node - shows promise, uses PDFKit as rendering engine
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-html-pdf - shows promise, although limited user base

Any suggestions?